# Hold & Release button code keeps running the first animations completion block

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uiview

I'd like to hold a button for 1 second, watching it fade to a new color until I release that button, at which point I'd want the animation to cancel and return to the original color

My problem is that I also want to cancel the completion block attributed to the first action, in the event that the second action happens before the first completes (user releases button before it's fully changed color)

below code is how I'm trying to do it but the completion block for action 1 finishes every time no matter what. Should I be taking a completely different route with this functionality?

```
- (void)animate1On {

    [UIView animateWithDuration:1.0 animations:^{

        self.button1.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
        self.button1.alpha = 0.4;

    } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
        NSLog(@"ANIMATE ON COMPLETE");
    }];
}

- (void)animate1Off {

    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.4 animations:^{

        [self.button1.layer removeAllAnimations];

        self.button1.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
        self.button1.alpha = 0.2;

    } completion:^(BOOL finished) {

        NSLog(@"ANIMATE OFF COMPLETE");

    }];
}
```

below is separate code I use to create the button and assign the touchDown (hold) and touchupinside (release) calls

```
    self.button1 = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    self.button1.frame = button1rect;
    self.button1.tag = 100;
    [self.button1 setTitle:@"1" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    self.button1.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
    self.button1.layer.borderWidth = 0;
    self.button1.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
    self.button1.alpha = 0.2;
    [self.button1 addTarget:self action:@selector(animate1On) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
    [self.button1 addTarget:self action:@selector(animate2Off) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [self.view addSubview:self.button1];
```

Comment: In `animate1Off` have you tried moving `[self.button1.layer removeAllAnimations];` outside of the animation block? Place it before the animation block so that it's the first thing that's executed.

Comment: just tried, doesn't change anything. it seems removeAllAnimations runs the completion block for currently running animations

Comment: No worries. See my answer for the solution to your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Completion blocks will execute when the animation has finished or when it's removed. The `finish` boolean flag is there to help you decide whether or not you should execute the code in the completion block. So your completion block in `animate1On` should be as follows:

```
completion:^(BOOL finished) {
    if (!finished) {
        return;
    }

    NSLog(@"ANIMATE ON COMPLETE");
}
```

This will ensure that the `NSLog` line will only execute if the animation has finished.

Answer (score 0):

For now when you press the button you just run your method from beginning to the end, it's not cancelled when you release the touch. The best option would be create custom button and override touchesBegan:withEvent, move and end methods.

But I think for simple solution you can also change your methods to accept sender as parameter:

```
- (void)animate1On:(id)sender{...}
- (void)animate1Off:(id)sender{...}
```

And when you press the button and keep it let the animation happened but when you release touch call your animate off method and cancel all of the animation for the sender:

```
UIButton *btn = (UIButton*)sender;
[btn.layer removeAllAnimations];
//.... all of your code here
```

I haven't test it but you can try, it should work.

Comment: I believe I'm doing the same thing as I'm using strong properties to access self.button1.layer for all my animation work